# Issue with adding constraint to route

Tags: regex, vb.net, routes

I am adding a route on a website, and I want 2 constraints. The first constraint is that the first parameter should be 2 characters lower case, and the second value to be alphanumeric to include hyphens. I have it built out but it always errors when I try accessing the page. If I remove the second constraint, the error is not thrown. Here is the constraint that I made:

```
      routes.MapPageRoute("landing", "{locale}/destinations/{destination}", "~/home-brand.aspx",
                        True,
                        New RouteValueDictionary(New With
                            {.locale = "en", .destination = "a-page"}),
                        New RouteValueDictionary(New With
                            {.locale = "[a-z]{2}", .destination = "[\w\-]"}))
```

Now if I add a character limit to destination like so:

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("landing", "{locale}/destinations/{destination}", "~/home-brand.aspx",
                        True,
                        New RouteValueDictionary(New With
                            {.locale = "en", .destination = "a-page"}),
                        New RouteValueDictionary(New With
                            {.locale = "[a-z]{2}", .destination = "[\w\-]{2,20}"}))
```

The page resolves without any issues. Why did it not work on the first instance, but worked in the second?

Comment: the first one is only capturing one character

Comment: What is the problem? Does the second snippet work fine?

Comment: @stribizhev The second snippet works fine. My issue was with the first snippet. I thought the regular expression in destination in the first snippet would check against all characters.

Comment: To check *all* the input from start to end, use `^`, `$`, and `*`: `"^[\w\-]*$"`. Please check and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check *all* the input from start to end, use start/end of string anchors ("zero-width assertions") `^` and `$`, and also use a `*` quantifier matching 0 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern:

```
^[\w-]*$
```

Here is [the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cw-%5d*%24&i=Some-words)

Note that you do not have to escape the hyphen at the end of the character class.

Comment: Glad it works for you. If you found my answer helpful please also consider upvoting it.